# How to achieve abstraction without using interfaces and abstract classes in java

Tags: abstraction

I was asked this question in one of my interviews and still dont have answer to it. If by abstraction we only mean , you not able to instantiate object(as applicable for interfaces and abstract classes), so having a private constructor is the answer?
Abstraction is explained in varied ways all over internet . Even using System.out.println is abstraction as we dont know detail behind it .
Using factory classes is also abstraction as we dont know which subclass will be instantiated.
Calling any method within an API is also abstraction.
I am actually confused now, as to what the interviewer wanted as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstraction is all about hiding implementation, like how the gas pedal to a car abstracts you from the various complexities in making a car go.

A simple way of doing it is to just use `private` members. `GetActiveServers()` could call no `private` methods, or 5 `private` methods. That doesn't really matter when we're using it, so long as it works efficiently as needed.

I think he was trying to trick you because of the `abstract` keyword sort've means something different from `abstraction`, but it's not entirely unrelated.